# Error while installing nvm in mac using brew

Tags: ruby, macos, nvm, homebrew-cask

I am trying to install nvm using brew. i am trying to use the following command to install nvm, but getting the below error. Any help is appreciated.

**Command:**

```
 brew cask install nvm
```

**Error:**

```
Error: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=unknown state
Follow the instructions here:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask#reporting-bugs
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:933:in `connect_nonblock'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:933:in `connect'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:319:in `open_http'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:737:in `buffer_open'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:212:in `block in open_loop'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:210:in `catch'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:210:in `open_loop'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:151:in `open_uri'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:717:in `open'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with SSL ciphers settings and ones in the server.
Try updating at least one of Homebrew / Ruby / OpenSSL.

more about this:

- https://github.com/rvm/rvm/pull/1764
- [SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33292097/ssl-connect-syscall-returned-5-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-hello-a-openssl)
- https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/issues/253